# Código para identificar navegador no WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, html5, wordpress

Preciso de um código que identifique se o navegador é Firefox e depois execute um bloco de código e caso contrario execute outro. O bloco de código é `HTML5` puro.

O código é pra ser usado dentro do Wordpress, por isso acredito só aceitar `HTML`, mas se não houver outra forma pode ser em `PHP` ou `Javascript`.

---

Irmão, 
Estou usando o modulo wordpress em um site próprio. O que quero fazer é o seguinte:
O site é um portal de notícias. Nele coloquei um player da minha rádio online.  O código é o seguinte:

```
<iframe src="http://player.srvstm.com/player-barra/19378/000000" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="31"></iframe>
```

Percebi que este player não roda no Firefox e queria colocar um código alternativo somente para ele em Html5, este abaixo:

```
<div id="player-html5" class="players">
<audio id="radios-player" controls="" preload="none" autoplay="" src="http://stm3.srvstm.com:19378/;"></audio>
```

pensei em usar um IF em alguma linguagem pra identificar o navegador, mas não sei se é a solução mais viável.

O site é: www.planetariosdigital.com.br

Comment: O Wordpress é feito em PHP, você pode mudar "tudo" nele. Se você estiver usando o https://wordpress.com você realmente só irá conseguir usar HTML. É necessário mais detalhares.

Comment: adicionei mais detalhes acima. Vê se dá pra entender agora

Comment: O código em HTML 5 funciona em todos os navegadores (incluindo o Firefox) correto? Porque não usa ele como padrão?! É possível fazer isso usando `is.js` (http://is.js.org/), então usar `if(is.firefox()){ }else{}`. Porém, se um código funciona em todos, use ele. A situação de buscar alternativa especifica para cada navegador é quando cada um exige um "código" diferente, o que não é o caso, pois um código consegue funcionar em todos (a segunda opção).

Comment: Não utilizei o `html5` como padrão por que não achei customização para ele. Ele puro é muito simples, mas vou continuar procurando personalização para o player em `html5`. Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para resolver o seu problema a minha solução é com javascript. Porém para que o meu código funcione é preciso que você faça uma pequena alteração no seu código iframe, preciso que você adicione um id, ficando desta forma:

Código original:

```
<iframe src="http://player.srvstm.com/player-barra/19378/000000" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="31"></iframe>
```

Código Modificado:

```
<iframe id="player" src="http://player.srvstm.com/player-barra/19378/000000" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="31"></iframe>
```

Eu preciso deste id para ser possível manipular o player na pagina com o javascript.

Agora você deverá colocar este código PHP no functions.php do Wordpress, para que ele adicione o código javascript responsável por identificar se o internauta está no firefox.

Caso sim ele irá remover o player atual e trocar pelo player do html5.

Função PHP:

```
 add_action('wp_footer', 'firefox_player_audio_javascript', 100);

function firefox_player_audio_javascript() {
echo "<script>if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
var iframe = document.getElementById('player');
var containeriframe = iframe.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.id = \"radios-player\";
audio.setAttribute(\"controls\", \"\");
audio.preload = \"none\";
audio.setAttribute(\"autoplay\", \"\");
audio.src = \"http://stm3.srvstm.com:19378/;\";
iframe.remove();
containeriframe.appendChild(audio);
}</script>";
}
```

Lembrando que para acessar os functions.php você vai em:

Painel Administrativo do Wordpress → Aparência → Editor

[image: Local onde você pode acessar o editor de código do wordpress]

Na lateral direita -> Você devará encontrar o functions.php ou em português Funções do tema

[image: Functions.php do wordpress]

Por fim salve a função no final do arquivo e veja o resultado:

[image: Salvando função no wordpress]

Enfim espero que funcione, boa sorte!